# How to customize default back button in UINavigationView ios7

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationbar, ios7, segue

I am using Navigation View Controller in storyboard to creates different views linked together by segue link. Therefore, all the back button are automatically created.
I have tried many ways to customize that back button with other text, or just no text but still cannot.

Here are the methods I tried,

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"abc";
```

or

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"abc";
```

or

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"abc";
```

Please help me this one, thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can edit the back button's title in storyboards directly. Select the appropriate ViewController that's been imbedded in a NavigationController and then:

[image]

Comment: What if you're not using a storyboard/xib file?

Comment: [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html]


_If you want to specify a custom image or title for the back button, you can assign a custom bar button item (with your custom title or image) to this property instead._

Haven't tried this lately - but I think this is the direction to the solution if you want to do it programmatically